# Bootstrap inline checkbox layout is cramped

Tags: checkbox, bootstrap-4

My checkbox text is too narrow but I don't know why. I've tried using flex-grow, and whitespace: nowrap, to no avail. What am I doing wrong:

[image]

Comment: Please post the code in the question.

Comment: @Zim you can see the HTML on the side

Comment: yes, I can, but it doesn't make it easy to repro the issue. It also doesn't show what's in the adjacent form groups.